# ResultSetMetaData getScale returns 0

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a table called `RATE_HISTORY` with a field called `RATE`.
The `RATE` field has scale 18.
I am using `ResultsetMetaData` to get meta-data of columns in this table on Oracle 11.2.
I execute the following query in my code:

```
select (RATE * 100) from RATE_HISTORY
```

When I do `metadata.getScale()`, it returns 0. However, if I execute this query:

```
select RATE from RATE_HISTORY
```

`getScale` returns the correct value (18).
Is there a way to multiply two numbers in oracle and keep the scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting the result in the select should also work, the downside is that you have to repeat the scale from the column definition:

```
select cast(RATE * 100 as number(30, 18)) from RATE_HISTORY
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this happens because the scale is an artifact of the table column, not the data itself. When you derive a value from the column value, you lose that meta-data.

How about using

```
select RATE, (RATE * 100) from RATE_HISTORY
```

You can get the scale from the first column, the calculation from the second.

Or just do the multiplication in java, of course.