# resultsetmetadata.getScale() returns 0 when using aggregate functions like min or max

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, metadata

In an java application I select numeric values from an oracle database. I need to know the number of digits right to the comma of the selected values, so I used the `getScale()` method of the `ResultSetMetaData` Class. This approach works fine as long as I do not use aggregate functions like min, max... in my `select` statement. When using min or max `getScale()` returns 0. `ColumnType` is still the same `(NUMERIC)` as the column value is.

Any ideas what the reason might be? Also I'm still looking for a workaround that is not too awkward.

We use: `oci driver, Java 6, Oracle 10g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, any expression is of an unknown scale. For instance, the `AVG` of a numeric column  cannot rely on the column's original scale. It is up to the client to deal with that. How could you know the precision of a `SUM` unless you had the actual value? Similarly, what is the length of a string returned after it has been through an `RTRIM` or `REPLACE` function? You don't have a way to know until you look at the actual values of the entire result set.

Perhaps in the SQL itself you can know what the appropriate scale is. This question suggests using a `cast` to the appropriate type.

[ResultSetMetaData getScale returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354176/resultsetmetadata-getscale-returns-0)

In your case, you're asking about `min` and `max`. These are special in that they maintain the scale and precision of the column. Maybe not in the driver, but logically speaking they do. If you *must* know the scale, you can look at the metadata of the column itself rather than the result set's metadata using `java.sql.DatabaseMetadata` methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer. I do not have big influence on the sql statements, so casting and databasemetadata are not available options for me. Do you know how to get the used comma character from within java, so I could look at the value as you said? Although it's not resolving my problem I mark your post as solution since it is a perfect answer to my question. Thanks

Comment: For numeric columns, one option is to always retrieve with `getBigDecimal()` and figure out the  scale from that.